# Transparent PNG image doesn't regard background color, and acts as not transparent

Tags: html, css

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <title>My Website</title>

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
    <div id="center-box">
        <ul>
            <li id="fim"><img src="images/1.png" /></li>
            <li id="sim"><img src="images/2.png" /></li>
            <li id="tim"><img src="images/3.png" /></li>
            <li id="fom"><img src="images/4.png" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS Code

```
html {
    height:100%;
}
body {
    background:black;
    border:1px solid white;
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    }
#center-box {
    border:4px solid white;
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-150px;
    margin-top:-150px;
    background:grey;
    }
#center-box ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:5px;
    padding:18px;
}
#center-box ul li {
    display:inline;
}
#center-box ul li:hover  {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

It only has a box in the middle of a page, and an inline list with images that are transparent (PNG). I want to make a transparent image change its background color by hovering on it, but it acts as the image is not transparent. How would you suggest to fix this?

Comment: This problem only happens on IE6 I guess?? Or IE specific Browsers

Comment: No. It happens on both the newest IE and Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use "inline-block" display for your *li* element in your CSS :

```
#center-box ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

That way, the background will not only be applied on the text part of the area, but on the whole image.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is an alpha transparency problem in IE6 with respect to the images with the PNG format. Since the support for the alpha channel was missing for these browsers there are some tags that can support your code.

If you want it through CSS

```
img {
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(...);
}
```

If you want it through JavaScript

```
img.style.filter = "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(...)";
```

You can check the further pitfalls which these will have [here](http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6/)

Comment: +1 Just missing that IE6 degrades well to full transparency for PNG-8 images. This is often an acceptable solution. It might not look that great but basically works in IE6 then. The AlphaImageLoader should imho be avoided if possible because it is a performance killer.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a complex way of doing it, but it works with inline-block. Now it marks whole background :)

Comment: @FabianBarney yeah I know about it thats why I have mentioned in the link to check out its pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

Transparent PNGs work well for me with background behind them as long as the browser is IE 7+.  I suspect your PNGs may not be transparent.

Comment: Actually, they are transparent, but I just found the problem. I used inline list elements, so when I hovered on the image, only the bottom was marked, because it is not a block. Inline-block works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For < IE7:
These browsers do not support PNG alpha transparency.
However PNG-8 images with alpha transparency are rendered with full transparency.
But truecolor PNG's alpha transparency appear grey when they get rendered.

So use PNG-8 images when possible and you're done. Otherwise you've to drop browser support or use workarounds like Shiv mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity ... have you tested this in older versions of IE?

The `:hover` pseudo class does not apply to all elements and `inline-block` can only be applied to inline elements (list items are block level) in IE7 and none in IE6.

I take it that you'll be using `<a>` inside your `<li>`; this should fix both issues (over-and-above the transparency issue of course).

Comment: Yes, I am going to use hyperlinks that are going to be attached to the images.